# Domain not catching error/Missing error handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

General overview of the code:
I'm trying to merge Express and Socket.IO session management using Redis. Seems to work thus far, but I'm having trouble trapping errors using domains as seen in the test below.

Server code:

```
"use strict";

var domain = require("domain");
var redis = require("redis");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var socketio = require("socket.io");
var redisSio = require("socket.io-redis");

// Configure Express:
app.use(require("compression")());
app.use(require("body-parser").json());
var expressSession = require("express-session");
// Configure Socket.IO:
app.io = socketio(server, {
  transports: ["websocket", "polling"],
  // Same name as Express cookie:
  cookie: "test.sid"
});
// Manage Socket.IO sessions using Redis:
app.io.adapter(redisSio({socket: "/tmp/redis.sock"}));
// Manage Express sessions using Redis:
app.use(expressSession({
  // Same name as Socket.IO cookie:
  name: "test.sid",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: "secret",
  store: redis.createClient("/tmp/redis.sock", {
      return_buffers: true
    })
}));

var d = domain.create();
d.on("error", function(err) { console.log("Error"); });
d.run(function() {
  // Configure listener for Socket.IO connections:
  app.io.on("connection", d.bind(function(socket) {
    // Configure listener for specific event:
    socket.on("channel", d.bind(function(data, callback) {
      // "data" is general data incoming from client.
      // "callback" is a client function meant for acknowledgments.
      // Generate an error:
      null.test();
    }));
  }));
});

// Start the server:
server.listen(8080);
```

Client code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var sock = io.connect();

    if(sock) {
      sock.emit("channel", null, function(data) {
        $("#tester").text(JSON.stringify(data));
      });
    }
    if(sock) {
      sock.disconnect();
      sock = null;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="tester"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When receiving the event from the client (triggering the error), the following is printed to the console:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: Cannot call method 'test' of null
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/debian/test.js:46:12)
    at Socket.b (domain.js:183:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.onevent (/home/debian/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:330:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/home/debian/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:290:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (/home/debian/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/home/debian/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/home/debian/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
    at Client.ondata (/home/debian/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:175:18)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

Why isn't the domain catching the error? And why is it complaining about a missing error handler on `socket`?

Relevant package versions:

- Node.js (v0.10.38) and also io.js (v2.5.0)
- Express (4.13.3)
- Socket.IO (1.3.6)

Comment: You dont have a socket.on('error') call

Comment: @bluesman  Correct, I want the domain to catch it; along with any other errors taking place in the domain's run() method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461234/domains-not-properly-catching-errors-while-testing-nodejs-in-mocha

Comment: @bluesman Yes, I saw that question as well and adding `process.nextTick()` didn't help because the code is already asynchronous.

Comment: Are you sure the error is not intercepted by socket and is bubbled up?

Comment: So you're saying `socket` catches the error and prints that stack trace to stdout itself? It doesn't bubble up at all because the domain error handler never executes (it should print `Error` to stdout if it did).